# Any source or method to download Macrotrends.net URLs?

Tags: web-scraping

I wanna to scrape the data from [www.macrotrends.net](http://www.macrotrends.net), I have a list of stock symbols but the URL of macrotrends.net includes a company short name and symbol. Like this:

```
https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/GILD/gilead-sciences/balance-sheet
```

May I know where can I find the URL short name for all US stock companies?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the real base url by first going to the incorrect url. For example, if you go to https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/AAPL/ , you will see "page not found". But the url will have conveniently changed to https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/AAPL/apple/ . You can get that new url using a chromedriver. Here is a short script that will go through every symbol in a given list and write the real base url to a text file:

```
import sys, os
import time
from selenium import webdriver


def getDriver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {}
    prefs['profile.default_content_settings.popups'] = 0
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    return webdriver.Chrome('./driver/chromedriver.exe', options=options)


def main(write_mode):
    print('')

    if write_mode != 'w' and write_mode != 'a':
        return 1

    driver = getDriver()
    with open('symbols_all.txt', 'r') as symbols_file, \
        open('macrotrends_map.txt', write_mode) as map_file:
        for line in symbols_file.readlines():
            symbol = line.replace('\n', '').split(',')[0]
            if symbol > '':
                while True:
                    try:
                        url = f'https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/{symbol}'
                        driver.get(url)
                        time.sleep(2)
                        base_url = driver.current_url if driver.current_url != url else 'ERROR'
                        map_file.write(symbol + ',' + base_url + '\n')
                        map_file.flush()
                        print(symbol + ',' + base_url)
                        break
                        
                    except: # in case internet goes out
                        print('...')
                        time.sleep(15)

    print('\nSuccess!\n')
    return 1
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os._exit(main(sys.argv[1]))
```